# React Native StackNavigator animation direction

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I feel like this is something that should be somewhat easy but can't find any info on the topic? Right now (on Ios) when I click the button and navigation is activated, the screen animation moves left. Is there a way to change this to a different direction? Also, how do I get this same animation to happen on android? I haven't run it on android yet but sounds like there is no animation at all. Thanks!

where its called:

```
<Button title='Create Account' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('signup')} />
```

navigator stack:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='login'>
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name='login' component={loginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='details' component={DetailScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name='signup' component={SignUp} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `screenOptions` to `Stack.Navigator` like this:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{cardStyleInterpolator: fadeNavigation}}>
```

and define transition animation like this:

```js
const fadeNavigation = ({current}) => ({
  cardStyle: {
    opacity: current.progress,
  },
});
```

You can find more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations)